Uniform convergence of derivatives for certain convex functions.
I have three sequences of real functions $\{f^-_n\}_{n\ge0}, \{f_n\}_{n\ge0} , \{f^+_n\}_{n\ge0}$ defined on an interval $I \subseteq [0,+\infty)$ such that:

this functions are normalized logarithms of certain partition functions
they are all smooth
they are all strictly convex
$\forall x \in I$ it holds $f_n(x)-\frac 1 {n^2} \le f^-_n(x) \le f_n(x) \le f^+_n(x) \le f_n(x)+\frac 1 {n^2}$
they all converge uniformly to the same analytic limit $f(x)$ as $n \to +\infty$
derivatives of every order of $f^-_n$ and $f^+_n$ converge uniformly and the limits are the same for the two sequences (equivalent to: limit $n \to +\infty$ and derivation are interchangeable)

I would like to prove that 5. holds for the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge0}$, or at least that $\{f_n'''\}_{n\ge0}$ converge uniformly.
I can prove (exploiting convexity) that $\{f_n'\}_{n\ge0}$ converge locally uniformly.
Even though usually nothing can be inferred for derivatives, this setting seems to me to have some rigidity.
Does this seem to be reasonable? Does anybody have a counterexample or a proof for this?

I think you can come up with a simple counterexample, using something whose second derivative oscillates fast enough: $f_n(x)=x^2+\frac{\cos(nx)}{2n^2}$, $f_n^-(x)=x^2-\frac 1{2n^2}$, $f_n^+(x)= x^2+\frac 1{2n^2}$.
